# Is the wave packet of a relativistic quantum particle oblate (flattened) or prolate (elongated)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, particle-physics, wavefunction

A free, non-relativistic wave packet of a quantum particle is usually thought of as having spherical shape. What happens for a particle moving relativistically? For an outside observer, is the wave packet oblate (flattened in the direction of motion) or prolate (elongated in the direction of motion)?

**In a few words: is a relativistic probability cloud flattened or elongated?**

Or maybe the question does not make any sense?

Comment: Here are two references dealing  mathemtically with relativistic particles, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.6260.pdf    https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.6260 . Maybe you can find your answer in their formulas .

Comment: Thank you! But that is only one reference ...

Comment: Sorry, here is the other one and it has a lot of references https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01714 .